# 2011 1.2 Fiesta a/c not cool & temperature light

Tags: ford, ac, temperature

I was driving my car and the a/c started to blow uncool air and light came up for the temperature which only stayed on for a short time. 
This happened after going through a drive through with having the windows open and a/c on. Not sure if they are related and what caused this issue

Answer (score 1):

So you got a high temp light while waiting in drive thru, right? And then AC went off. That's normal. The question is why it overheated. Start by checking coolant level and condition. Then check radiator fan operation. A fully functional cooling system should not overheat while waiting at a drive thru, even with AC on. This sounds like a cooling system issue, not AC